# How many Pokémon were available at the release of Pokémon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have googled for this, but can't really put the proper terms to find an answer.

At the initial release of Pokémon Go, how many Pokémon were available? I seem to remember legendaries like Mew and Mewtwo were not, at least, but I can't confirm this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there were no Mew / Mewtwo, or any other Legendary Pokémon, and Ditto weren't available (so there were only 145 Pokémons):
[Here's list of the Pokémons that were available at launch.](https://pokemongo.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_forms_by_release_date/2016#July_6th)

Comment: While not really a part of the question, it's worth nothing that region exclusives were a thing at initial release, and trading wasn't implemented either. So Tauros, Mr. Mime, Kangaskhan, and Farfetch’d weren't *globally* available without spoofing or traveling